# Puppet doesnt sign certs

Tags: debian, puppet, debian-squeeze

I have build an testlab for puppet, but it doesn't work. I start `puppet agent` on the node and it waits for the certificate.

```
root:~# puppet agent --server xxxx --waitforcert 60 --test
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
```

On the Server, now pending certificate requests are found:

```
root:~# puppet cert --list                                                                                                        
root:~#
```

In the masterhttpd log:

```
root:~# tail /var/log/puppet/masterhttp.log
[2012-01-06 09:19:17] xxx - - [06/Jan/2012:09:19:17 CET] "GET /production/certificate/xx HTTP/1.1" 404 30
[2012-01-06 09:19:17] - -> /production/certificate/pgw
[2012-01-06 09:19:47] xxx - - [06/Jan/2012:09:19:47 CET] "GET /production/certificate/xx HTTP/1.1" 404 30
[2012-01-06 09:19:47] - -> /production/certificate/pgw
[2012-01-06 09:19:47] xxx - - [06/Jan/2012:09:19:47 CET] "GET /production/certificate/xx HTTP/1.1" 404 30
[2012-01-06 09:19:47] - -> /production/certificate/pgw
[2012-01-06 09:19:47] xxx - - [06/Jan/2012:09:19:47 CET] "GET /production/certificate/xx HTTP/1.1" 404 30
[2012-01-06 09:19:47] - -> /production/certificate/pgw
```

The certificate file is not found.

Comment: once you run the puppet for te first time with `waitforcert` enabled then try running it again without `waitforcert`. Chances are that your cert is already signed and that is why `puppet cert --list` is empty.

Comment: `root:~# puppetca revoke --list                                                                                                   12-01-06 10:25
err: Could not call list: Could not find a certificate for revoke`

looks like not an signed cert :(

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you start the puppet agent as

```
$ puppet agent --server=xxxx --test --debug
```

this command will give  you more details why it is failing. Also, you may need tgo allow more time for it to complete.

You can also try to remove the certificate from sides if any (on master and agent respectively)

```
puppet --cert --clean your_machine_name

rm -rf /etc/puppet/ssl
```

Comment: "debug" delivers me no one new news. He waits for the certifcate and runs in the timeout. I think it is a Problem on the Server-side.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into very similar problems when I first started with Puppet. The --server option was not being respected.

Try adding an entry to your HOSTS file with the name of 'puppet' and the IP of your master box.

If that works the following syntax works well (at least for version 2.7.5)

```
[main]
logdir = /var/log/puppet
rundir = /var/run/puppet
ssldir = $vardir/ssl
server = puppetmaster.yourdomain.org
pluginsync = true

[agent]
classfile = $vardir/classes.txt
localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
server = puppetmaster.yourdomain.org
listen = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you verified that the agent is getting to the master. Good first step.

Next, as others have suggested, verify that the certificate wasn't signed and that you just didn't miss it:

```
sudo puppet cert --list --all
```

If you don't see it there, I'd clean everything up and start over.

First, confirm that the date and time on both servers are in sync. You could force an NTP sync with something like `ntpd -q -g`, depending on your distro and NTP client.

Then, run a `clean` on the puppet master:

```
sudo puppet cert clean <agent hostname>
```

On the agent, clean up all your SSL files:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/puppet/ssl /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ /var/puppet/ssl
```

Finally, run a test:

```
sudo puppet agent --debug --test --server <master hostname>
```

Hopefully, if this doesn't address the issue, this should yield you some clues as to where to look.